# How to detect if the path of a url starts with a certain word

Tags: url, preg-match

I'm trying to figure out how to get the page name from a facebook page and although I've figured out how to get it from the `http://www.facebook.com/pagename` version, I can't figure out how to test and get it from the longer version that looks like this `http://www.facebook.com/pages/pagename/433425324544`. How can I test to see if the path starts with `/pages` and how can I extract the pagename from it all using one function. Here's what I use to get the page name in the standard form.

```
function get_facebook_username( $facebook_url ) { 
$url = $facebook_url;
$result = preg_match("/(https|http)?:\/\/(www\.)?facebook\.com\/?([^\/]*)/", $url, $matches);
$fb_username = 'default value';
if($result == 1){
    $fb_username = $matches[3];
} else {
    return;
}

echo "$fb_username";
}
```

I found a better way to do this I think except it cuts the last letter off the username if the url is in it's shortened version. For example.

```
//---short
$url = http://www.facebook.com/pagename
//---long
$url  = http://www.facebook.com/pages/pagename/7532527927346

<?php
  $url = $facebook_username;
  $path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
  $pathTrimmed = trim($path, 'pages/../0123456789');
  echo $pathTrimmed;
?>

//---short
 pagenam
//---long
 pagename
```

Why is the short version missing the last letter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would go about this is to use `explode` to place the url into an array using the below code:

```
$url  = "http://www.facebook.com/pages/pagename/7532527927346";
$result = explode("/", $url);
```

You get the following array:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "http:"
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
  [2]=>
  string(16) "www.facebook.com"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "pages"
  [4]=>
  string(8) "pagename"
  [5]=>
  string(13) "7532527927346"
}
```

Then a simple if $result[3] == "pages" will allow you to check if the url contains pages.

**Ninja Edit**
In place of explode, you can also use the `preg_split` which will return no empty array elements:

```
$result = preg_split("~/~", $url, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: quick question. So say I parse the url down to the path and then do preg_split. How can I remove `/pages` and `/238327033`. I tried trimming but that removes parts of the pagename if I trim `/pages`